# Как объединить один аккаунт с двумя система входа?

Tags: php, yii2

Есть самопальная система регистрации и входа, как позволить пользователю входит в свой аккаунт не с помощью самопальной система, а при помощи гугла?

Comment: Я имею введу как пользователю заходить под один аккаунт через разные системы входа.

Comment: OpenID - погуглите